# passMessageObject from ObjC to Swift (wormhole)

Tags: ios, swift, nscoding

Trying to use "WormHole" in Swift (from [link](https://github.com/mutualmobile/MMWormhole)), the following translation from Objective C to Swift does not seem to work. Do you have any hint on how to do it ?

My Swift-code (not working yet!!!) is:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var numberLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var segmentedControl: UISegmentedControl!

    // Initialize the wormhole
    let wormhole = MMWormhole(applicationGroupIdentifier: "group.ch.ideenkaffee.wormhole", optionalDirectory: "wormhole")

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        // Obtain an initial message from the wormhole  
        // ERROR occurs here !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
        let messageObject: AnyObject? = wormhole.messageWithIdentifier("button")
        if let number = messageObject!.valueForKey("buttonNumber") as? Int {
            numberLabel.text = ("\(number.value)")
        }

        // Become a listener for changes to the wormhole for the button message
        wormhole.listenForMessageWithIdentifier("button", listener: { (messageObject) -> Void in
            // The number is identified with the buttonNumber key in the message object
            if let number = messageObject.valueForKey("buttonNumber") as? Int {
                self.numberLabel.text = ("\(number.value)")
            }
        })

        self.segmentedControlValueDidChange(segmentedControl)
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    @IBAction func segmentedControlValueDidChange(sender: UISegmentedControl) {

        if let title = segmentedControl.titleForSegmentAtIndex(segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex) {
            // Pass a message for the selection identifier. The message itself is a NSCoding compliant object
            // with a single value and key called selectionString.
            wormhole.passMessageObject(["selectionString":title], identifier: "selection")
        }
    }

}
```

The original Objective-C code was :

```
@interface ViewController ()

@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UILabel *numberLabel;
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UISegmentedControl *segmentedControl;

@property (nonatomic, strong) MMWormhole *wormhole;

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Initialize the wormhole
    self.wormhole = [[MMWormhole alloc] initWithApplicationGroupIdentifier:@"group.com.mutualmobile.wormhole"
                                                         optionalDirectory:@"wormhole"];

    // Obtain an initial message from the wormhole
    id messageObject = [self.wormhole messageWithIdentifier:@"button"];
    NSNumber *number = [messageObject valueForKey:@"buttonNumber"];

    self.numberLabel.text = [number stringValue];

    // Become a listener for changes to the wormhole for the button message
    [self.wormhole listenForMessageWithIdentifier:@"button" listener:^(id messageObject) {
        // The number is identified with the buttonNumber key in the message object
        NSNumber *number = [messageObject valueForKey:@"buttonNumber"];
        self.numberLabel.text = [number stringValue];
    }];

    [self segmentedControlValueDidChange:self.segmentedControl];
}

- (IBAction)segmentedControlValueDidChange:(UISegmentedControl *)segmentedControl {
    NSString *title = [segmentedControl titleForSegmentAtIndex:segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex];

    // Pass a message for the selection identifier. The message itself is a NSCoding compliant object
    // with a single value and key called selectionString.
    [self.wormhole passMessageObject:@{@"selectionString" : title} identifier:@"selection"];
}

@end
```

Any help on the Swift-code is appreciated !

Comment: Never say "does not work". What actually happens and what is wrong with what actually happens? - Never say "ERROR occurs here". What error? Compile error or runtime error? Give the actual error message.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
if let toWatchOldMessage: AnyObject = wormhole.messageWithIdentifier("toWatch") {
        println("*ic getOldWormholeMessages toWatchOldMessage \(toWatchOldMessage)")
    } else {
        println("*ic getOldWormholeMessages toWatchOldMessage no message")
    }
```